# the request doesn't contain a multipart/form-data or multipart/mixed stream, content type header is false

Tags: java, javascript, jquery, ajax, file-upload

I wanna send an image through ajax but I get the following exception:

```
org.apache.commons.fileupload.FileUploadBase$InvalidContentTypeException: the request doesn't contain a multipart/form-data or multipart/mixed stream, content type header is false
```

surprisingly when I send this form regularly(not through ajax) form works fine.I tried changing Content-Type to multipart/form-data but then I get this exception:

```
org.apache.commons.fileupload.FileUploadException: the request was rejected because no multipart boundary was found
```

here is the jquery code:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#myform").submit(function(e) {
       e.preventDefault();
       var data = new FormData();
       data.append('file', document.formName.file.files[0]); // <-- possibly this line doesn't work
       $.ajax({
          url: 'upload.do',
          data: data,
          cache: false,
          contentType: false,
          processData: false,
          type: 'POST',
          success: function(res) {
          }
      });
   });
});
```

and the form:

```
 <form name="formName" enctype="multipart/form-data" id="myform" action="upload.do" method="POST">    
   <input type="file"  name="file" id="input-file" /> 
   <br>
   <input type="submit" value="Upload images" class="upload" />
 </form>
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.upload').click(function() {
        var input = document.getElementById('input-file');
        file = input.files[0];
        var data = new FormData();
        data.append('file', file);
        $.ajax({
            url: 'upload.do',
            data: data,
            cache: false,
            contentType: false,
            processData: false,
            type: 'POST',
            success: function(res) {
            }
        });
    });
});
```

Comment: sorry bro.nothing changed.

Comment: Try adding `alert(data)` before the ajax call and let me know if it contains anything.

Comment: In the first alert: [Object FormData]

Comment: and second alert was empty because in the servlet an exception occurred and the was no response to send.

Comment: Are you getting the same error? And please show what you have in `upload.do`.